# Bitcoin New Block Event Trigger

Tags: blockchain, block, relay

I want to know when a new block is discovered, I am watching debug.log to see if it has changed, I know there is a new block if the line contains "UpdateTip: new best". Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bitcoind` offers a [zmq hook](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/zmq.md) which you can use to receive notifications on new blocks and transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blocknotify option, Execute command when the best block changes, read more here https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin